# Disable KDE sounds in GNOME Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, audio, kde, kate

I use kate (a KDE text editor) under GNOME in Ubuntu. Since Natty upgrade, it plays miscellaneous sounds on error and other notifications.

I disabled sound notifications in GNOME, but kate sounds are still played. Kate itself doesn't seem to have any sound configuration, and I can't find any KDE configuration tool in the system menus.

How can I disable KDE notification sounds in a GNOME Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install KDE settings package `sudo apt-get install systemsettings`. Then open it up and go to **Application and System Notifications**, **Player Settings** tab, set **No audio output**.

Comment: My systemsettings doesn't have Application and System Notifications.
It has:

* Workspace  
   - Desktop Behavior  
   - Shortcuts  
* Personalization  
   - Regional Settings  
* Network  
   - Settings  
   - Connectivity  
* Hardware

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is rather overkill as it will mute *everything*, not just the error beeps, in KDE and prevent you from hearing things you actually want to hear.

Instead of going to the Player Settings tab, the individual error noises can be disabled in the Applications tab.

Comment: Unfortunately that requires you to individually silence about 500 different beep noises in twenty different places. There really needs to be a 'disable all' button.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a reason for these bloody noises anyway.  My solution that requires no installation of any more applications to take up space is to just delete the bloody noises:

`` sudo rm -fv `sudo find /usr/share -iname *.ogg` ``

Comment: Might want to limit that search path a bit to avoid deleting other sounds as well, but otherwise a good answer - Simplicity works!

Answer (score 1):

In case of Linux Mint 18.3 installing `systemsettings` didn't work, because the settings window was empty. [Here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=225&t=127885) I've found that the following is sufficient without installing additional packages (besides Krusader that I already had installed):

```
kcmshell4 kcmnotify
```

Then *Player Settings* -> *No audio output*.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

An update to @skfd answer, which pointed me in the right direction. The current location is in System Settings > Audio > Playback Streams. You can adjust or mute the "Notification Sounds" audio stream there.

The dinging sound made me crazy, going off even when doing mundane things like selecting a song on Spotify. So much better muted.